# Unable to connect App & Database servers in Sharepoint 2010 farm

Tags: domain-name-system, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have total of three machines connected to a machine which is promoted as Domain Controller (192.168.2.3).

- Machine 1 - WFE1 (192.168.2.4, Default Gateway - 192.168.2.3, DNS Server - 192.168.2.3)
- Machine 2 - App Server (192.168.2.5, Default Gateway - 192.168.2.3, DNS Server -   192.168.2.3)
- Machine 3 - Database Server (192.168.2.5,Default Gateway - 192.168.2.3, DNS Server - 192.168.2.3).

Sharepoint is installed in Machine 2 (App Server) and Database Server is installed in Machine 3 (Database Server).

Machine 2 and Machine 3 which are in the same domain are unable to ping each other.

How I can configure my SharePoint using this setup?

Comment: Have you disabled the Windows firewall?

Comment: "Unable to connect" can mean all sorts of things... Can you elaborate on the specific issue you're having?`

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems OK, except IP of machine 2 and 3 are the same, which would result in ip conflict.
Please change it to another IP.